# tmux prints long commands to beginning of same line without line break

Tags: bash, terminal, line-breaks, tmux

When typing a long command in tmux instead of printing to the next line the end of the command shows up at the beginning of the same line.

So instead of 

`user@computer:~$ aaaaaaaaaaa
aaaaa`

this happens

`aaaaacomputer:~$ aaaaaaaaaaa`

Using the standard terminal everything is fine.

Comment: See [Wooledge BashFAQ 53](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/053), "I have a fancy prompt with colors, and now bash doesn't seem to know how wide my terminal is. Lines wrap around incorrectly."

Comment: like https://superuser.com/questions/1266577/line-wrap-not-working-in-tmux/1266581#1266581

Answer (score 5):

If you have unescaped characters in your PS1 variable it might not wrap lines correctly.

Try

```
export PS1="\u@\h-\\$\[$(tput sgr0)\]"
```

If that fixes your problem you need to update your `.bashrc` file.

Answer (score -1):

The answer might be the content of your TERM variable.
What's the answer to

> echo $TERM

?

Get the value of TERM before starting tmux and compare it with the value withing tmux!
Try setting it to some other value like vt100 or xterm with

> export TERM=vt100

or

> export TERM=xterm